# Can I write videos pixel-by-pixel in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, video

I am trying to port a program from python (using OpenCV) to javascript/html, which generates a video where pixel colour are determined by a random function of its coordinates and its frame number.

I already created a program that creates still images in this fashion in javascript/html, but I'm having trouble with the video equivalent as I don't know how to *create a video from raw pixel data*, or if that's even possible.

I've already tried this code:

```js
var video = document.getElementById('Video')
var canvas = document.getElementById('Canvas')
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')
var apx = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, 200, 200);
var data = apx.data;

for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i+=4)
{
  data[i] = 255
  data[i+1] = 0
  data[i+2] = 0
  data[i+3] = 255
}
apx.data = data;
ctx.putImageData(apx, 0, 0);
ctx.drawImage(video, 0, 0)
```

```html
<canvas id='Canvas' width=200 height=200></canvas>
<video width=200 height=200 id='Video' controls></video>
```

(**fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gfkwhe3m/**)

But instead of creating a red video, it just creates a red square to the left of the video.
Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Don't need to output a video. Just keep generating the image over and over again in a `setTimeout/setInterval/requestAnimationFrame` loop

Comment: That's potentially an option, but I'd like it to be possible for them to somehow save the video, also each frame would take about 15-30 seconds to be generated, so I'd need to pregenerate the images and then play the video to achieve a reasonable FPS.

Comment: Okay, I have not read this, so it may not bring you any new information, but it was the closest I could find relating your issue: **http://html5doctor.com/video-canvas-magic/** (googled for *"javascript create video frame by frame"*)

Comment: Actually, this is the closest: **http://techslides.com/convert-images-to-video-with-javascript** (googled for *"javascript programmatically create a video using canvas"*)

Comment: Good luck Leo, but I warn you that you'r program's gonna be slow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the program to work by downloading [Whammy](https://github.com/antimatter15/whammy), as suggested by myfunkyside. To get it to work, I had to put the program inside the folder with Whammy. This code ended up working:

```
<canvas id='Canvas' width=200 height=200></canvas>
<video width=200 height=200 id='Video' controls></video>

<script src='whammy.js'></script>

<script>
var encoder = new Whammy.Video(15);
var video = document.getElementById('Video')
var canvas = document.getElementById('Canvas')
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')
var apx = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, 200, 200);
var data = apx.data;

for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i+=4)
{
    data[i] = 255
    data[i+1] = 0
    data[i+2] = 0
    data[i+3] = 255
}
apx.data = data;
ctx.putImageData(apx, 0, 0);

for(var i = 0; i<15; i++)
{
    encoder.add(ctx)
}

var output = encoder.compile()
var url = webkitURL.createObjectURL(output);
video.src = url

ctx.drawImage(video, 0, 0)
</script>
```

It ended up creating a one second completely red video.